Übersetzung der Redewendung "Now we're cooking!"
"Now we're cooking!" sagt man umgangssprachlich auf Englisch im Sinne von "Jetzt beginnt die echte Sache!" oder "Jetzt ist das, worum es geht, korrekt oder treffend."
Die beste Übersetzung, die ich ausdenken kann, wäre "Jetzt geht's los!", doch ich weiß nicht, ob das die beabsichtigte Meinung gut widerspiegelt. Vielleicht existiert noch eine passendere Variante?

Ich kenne eigentlich eher Now we're talking für etwas, wozu man So kommen wir ins Geschäft auf Deutsch sagt, aber ich nehme an, die Bedeutung ist dieselbe. Allerdings finde ich im Cambridge Dictionary (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-cooking) das Beispiel Now you're cooking und die Definition "to be making progress or doing something well". Auch wiktionary hat diese Formulierung (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/dictionary/now_you%27re_cooking) als feststehende Redewendung. Vielleicht kannst du die englische Bedeutung noch genauer spezifizieren?

My understanding is that "now you're cooking" is a shortened form of the now dated "now you're cooking with gas", a reference to how easy to use a gas stove is compared to a wood stove. (Apparently the gas industry was actively promoting the use of this line in movies and another media.) So you'd use this line when someone starts to do something in a new, highly efficient and effective way. A less idiomatic phrase: "you are really getting things done now'.

Staying in the rough area of phrase, one could use

Jetzt geht 's ans Eingemachte.

which is used to tell that we are now getting to the heart of things, to the difficult stuff, to the important stuff.
With similar meaning there is a reference to a famous writing from Goethe, Faust:

Jetzt kommen wir zu des Pudels Kern.

or just a plain

Jetzt geht 's erst richtig los.

If you rather mean something along the lines of "now we are really getting going", "now we are really working hard and making progress" (like RDBury's and Jonathan Herrera's comments might suggest), one could use

Jetzt klotzen wir richtig ran.


I don't know if it is in all German-speaking countries, but try: "Jetzt geht's um die Wurst!"

Which country uses this phrase?

I am from eastern central Germany and know the phrase. (However, I wouldn't use it entirely exchangeable with the ones in planetmaker's answer, which I consider a better fit for the question. It has a more adversarial character – e.g. you would use it when addressing the finalists of a competition. It implies that you can gain something.)

That phrase is in my active vocabulary, too - from North-Western Germany.

If you wanted to look at this from a Schwäbisch POV:

jetzt hudla!


But http://schwaebisches-woerterbuch.de/default.asp?q=hudla gives no such definition, as far, as I'm concerned. "Jetzt hudla" is more like "now no hustle", isn't it?
